# Is no-arg constructor(ignore default constructor as I have some arguments constructor) necessary for init method to work in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

In Spring, is a no-arg constructor necessary for init method to work(consider I have a constructor of one argument so default constructor does not come in the picture) because for me it is not working if I don't put a no-arg constructor. The exception is `No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.luv2code.springdemo.TrackCoach.<init>()`

Comment: Without seeing the code for `TrackCoach` this is impossible to answer. There is no need for a default constructor from Spring. Also the `<init>()` you see is the default constructor that isn't available, so something needs it. We don't know what because we don't now the `TrackCoach` class nor do we have the **full stacktrace**.

Answer (score 0):

A no-args constructor is needed when we use @entity annotation. Is it mandatory?

This has to do with how an ORM vendor has made the framework and what requirements he has made for it to work. Specifically for Hibernate yes it is mandatory.

Read Hibernate docs
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/quickstart/html_single/#hibernate-gsg-tutorial-basic-entity

2.2. The entity Java class

The no-argument constructor, which is also a JavaBean convention, is a requirement for all persistent classes. Hibernate needs to create objects for you, using Java Reflection. The constructor can be private. However, package or public visibility is required for runtime proxy generation and efficient data retrieval without bytecode instrumentation.